# Gwibber alternative for Facebook on 12.04

Tags: facebook, gwibber

I have browsed similar questions only to find people mainly asking for twitter alternatives. I would like to have something like Gwibber (which never worked for me till date) for using my Facebook on Ubuntu 12.04. I have both FB and Twitter (I have multiple accounts) open in different browsers which I want to avoid using. My primary requirement is support for at least one account of Facebook. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Desktop Facebook](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/fb-messenger-and-facebook-applications.html)

> Desktop Facebook app was created for the Ubuntu App Developer showdown contest in 2012. This application designed for Ubuntu Linux, it is written in PyGTK, designed with Glade and create with quickly that displays the Facebook website. It provides different buttons on the left side for easy access to various Facebook features. It also offers Facebook mobile within application, you can find mobile tab on left bottom corner. It has integrated search bar which is perfect for searching for friends, places, pages, and other stuff. If you want to contribute to this project, then contact folke-schwinning.

To install it run the following command in a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:folke-schwinning/personal`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install desktop-facebook`

Comment: I am facing a problem with this app. Even after I give remember me, it continues to ask for log in every time I starts it. :(

Comment: It is possible the app is no longer supported since the PPA hasn't been updated in a month. If you simply want a secure Facebook session, I recommend using NoScript and AdBlock Edge with your Firefox browser. You can also use self-destructing cookies. It will launch Facebook via its mobile site like the app should have done for you. Unfortunately, besides Desktop Facebook, FBMessager, and Gwibber, there aren't any Facebook apps for Ubuntu Desktop. If you want more information about the DF PPA, go here: https://launchpad.net/~folke-schwinning/+archive/personal

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have that account in Opera. Just that I different browser and many tabs, opening Opera with all those tabs take a lot of resources. Please do update if something new is available. So nice of you to help :)

Answer (score 1):

**FBMESSENGER**

FBMessenger is a stand-alone Facebook Messenger app for Linux, very similar to the official Messenger for Windows.

**features:**

- chat with your Facebook friends (obviously) in a separate window with
  tabs for each conversation;
- notifications and friend requests;
- friend updates;
- desktop popup alerts for notifications (only when you turn the chat
  on).

[image]

Install using the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fbmessenger
```

Comment: I was actually looking for timeline as well.

Comment: this is just a chat application.

Comment: Unfortunately, FBmessenger isn't working anymore! It stopped working the day Facebook stopped support for FBmessenger on windows. FBmessenger's developer has marked it as DEPRECATED on it's [GitHub page](https://github.com/oconnor663/fbmessenger).